# How to test component that is wrapped in HOC?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a an HOC that that only render the wrapped component when isEntityValid() is true:

```
export default WrappedComponent => {
  return class EntityConsumer extends Component {
    render() {
      return isEntityValid() && <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />;
    }
  };
};
```

the `export default` statement of my wrapped component looks like:

`export default withEnity(SomeComponent);`

`SomeComponent` had unit test cases written before I added the withEnity HOC,

```
  const wrapper = shallow(<SomeComponent {...props} />);
  const doneButton = wrapper.find(".footer_button");
```

how should I tweak the test so they will still pass?:

Comment: Depends on what isEntityValid is. You can either test wrapped component or mock withEnity and test a component and withEnity separately.

Comment: @estus I want mock withEnity and test the SomeComponent seperately, can you show me how to do it?

Comment: They are in different modules, aren't they? Then https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks.html

Comment: They are not in different modules.

Comment: Then you won't be able to mock it. As I said, the way it needs to be tested depends on what isEntityValid is.

Comment: @estus What if isEnityValid is a helper function in a different file in my file structure?

Comment: Then you likely may want to mock it to make unit test more isolated.

Comment: if you ensure `isEntityValid()`  returns `true`(maybe by mocking something  `isEntityValid` itself relies on/refers to) you may access `WrappedComponent` by [`wrapper.dive()`](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/dive.html). but much easier just exporting unwrapped version separately

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can export the unwrapped component too

```
export default withEnity(SomeComponent);
export { SomeComponent as PureSomeComponent };
```

And then test it unwrapped

```
Import { PureSomeComponent as SomeComponent};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I usually do my own hocs:

```
export default WrappedComponent => {
  class EntityConsumer extends Component {
    render() {
      return isEntityValid() && <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />;
    }
  };
  EntityConsumer.WrappedComponent = WrappedComponent;
  return EntityConsumer;
};
```

Then later on your test you can

```
const wrapper = shallow(<SomeComponent.WrappedComponent {...props} />);
const doneButton = wrapper.find(".footer_button");
```